# TapGestureRecognizer not work on Grid Row

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have proposed the following layout.

[image]

In the yellow area it will be reserved for a bar of options and user data. The red zone will be reserved for a listView and some options.

The problem is that when you put the layout in the following way:

```
<Grid 
   Grid.Row="1"
   Padding="0" 
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  IsVisible="{ Binding ErrorOccurred , Converter = { StaticResource InverseBoolConverter }  }">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="250" BackgroundColor="Yellow"></Grid>

      <StackLayout 
             x:Name="Body"
             Grid.Row="1"
             BackgroundColor="Red"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
             Padding="0"
            Spacing="0">
     </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

The scroll of the ListView and the TapGestureRecognizer that I have placed in the Red StackLayout. They do not work. Instead, I use a StackLayout instead of a Grid. Everything works. But I can not get the red StackLayout to occupy all the remaining space.

Someone knows I can be doing wrong?

This is the complete page code.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
        <Grid RowSpacing="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- APP Header -->
            <common:AppHeader 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Title="{i18n:Translate Page.Home.Title}"
                BackEnable="false">
                <common:AppHeader.Options>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
                        <common:RefreshOptionMenu />
                        <common:SettingsOptionMenu />
                        <common:SignOutOptionMenu />
                    </x:Array>
                </common:AppHeader.Options>

            </common:AppHeader>
            <!-- End APP Header -->

            <!--GRID WRAPPER-->
            <Grid 
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Padding="0" 
                 IsVisible="{ Binding ErrorOccurred , Converter = { StaticResource InverseBoolConverter }  }">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- PROFILE HEADER-->
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        HeightRequest="250"
                        Padding="0">

                        <!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
                        <Image 
                            Source="{ StaticResource HomeBackground }"
                            IsOpaque="false"
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                        <StackLayout

                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            Spacing="20">

                            <Grid 
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                TranslationY="25">

                                <!-- AVATAR -->
                                <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                                    x:Name="profileImage"
                                    CacheType="Disk"
                                    CacheDuration="30"
                                    WidthRequest="100"
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    FadeAnimationEnabled="true"
                                    ErrorPlaceholder="{ StaticResource ProfileErrorImage }"
                                    LoadingPlaceholder="{ StaticResource ProfileImagePlaceholder }"
                                    Source="{ Binding SelfParent.ProfileImage , Converter={ StaticResource ParentProfileImageURLConverter } }">
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                         <fftransformations:CircleTransformation BorderSize="5" BorderHexColor="#FFFFFF" />
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                 </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                                  <!-- BADGE -->
                                  <common:Badge
                                    IsVisible="{ Binding  AlertsPage.Remaining, Converter={ StaticResource ValueGreaterThanZeroConverter }}"
                                    BadgeText="{ Binding  AlertsPage.Remaining, StringFormat='+ {0}'}"
                                    BadgeTextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }"
                                    BadgeBackgroundColor="#22c064"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    TranslationX="40">

                                    <common:Badge.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToAlertsCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                    </common:Badge.GestureRecognizers>

                                </common:Badge>

                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding TakePhotoCommand }"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>

                            <!-- Parent FullName -->
                            <StackLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Padding="20">

                                <Label 
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Text="{Binding SelfParent.FullName}"
                                    TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                                        PortraitPhone=22,
                                        LandscapePhone=22,
                                        PortraitTablet=24,
                                        LandscapeTablet=24 }"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <!-- TOOLBAR -->
                        <Grid
                            x:Name="MenuGrid"
                            VerticalOptions="End"
                            Style="{ StaticResource ToolbarStyle }"
                            BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource TranslucidWhite }">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <!-- Children Action -->
                            <StackLayout
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Spacing="0">

                                <Label
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Users }"
                                    FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                    TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">

                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom 
                                            x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                            Phone="15" 
                                            Tablet="20" />
                                    </Label.FontSize>
                                </Label>

                                <Label
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding SelfParent.Children, StringFormat={i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Children} }"
                                    TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">
                                    <Label.FontSize>
                                        <OnIdiom 
                                            x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                            Phone="15" 
                                            Tablet="20" />
                                    </Label.FontSize> 
                                </Label>

                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToChildrenCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                             </StackLayout>

                               <!-- IsEnabled="{ Binding SelfParent.Children, Converter={ StaticResource ValueGreaterThanZeroConverter }}" -->
                              <!-- Results Action -->
                              <StackLayout
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Spacing="0">

                                    <Label
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.AreaChart }"
                                        FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom 
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                                Phone="15" 
                                                Tablet="20" />
                                         </Label.FontSize> 
                                     </Label>

                                      <Label
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Results}"
                                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">

                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom 
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                                Phone="15"
                                                Tablet="20" />
                                         </Label.FontSize> 
                                    </Label>

                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToResultsCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <!-- Profile Action -->
                            <StackLayout
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Spacing="0">

                                    <Label
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.User }"
                                        FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom 
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                                Phone="15" 
                                                Tablet="20" />
                                        </Label.FontSize> 
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Profile}"
                                        TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom 
                                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                                Phone="15" 
                                                Tablet="20" />
                                        </Label.FontSize> 
                                    </Label>

                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToProfileCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                               </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- END PROFILE HEADER-->

                       <StackLayout 
                                x:Name="Body"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                Padding="0">

                                <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <StackLayout  
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="18"
                                            Style="{ StaticResource CommonHeaderStyle }"
                                            Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Inbox }"
                                            FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }" />

                                        <Label
                                            Style="{ StaticResource CommonHeaderStyle }"
                                            Text="{ Binding ListAlertTitle }"/>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <StackLayout
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalOptions="End">

                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            HeightRequest="46"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Text="{ i18n:Translate Home.Show.Alerts }"/>

                                        <Label
                                            Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.ArrowRight }"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                            FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }" />

                                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToAlertsCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <!-- Last Alerts LIST -->
                                <ListView
                                    x:Name="AlertsListView"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding AlertsPage.Alerts}"
                                    RowHeight="90">

                                    <ListView.Behaviors>
                                        <utils:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                            EventName="ItemTapped"
                                            Command="{Binding ShowAlertDetailCommand}"
                                            EventArgsConverter="{ StaticResource ItemTappedEventArgsConverter }" />
                                    </ListView.Behaviors>

                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <commonControls:SearchPageViewCellWithId 
                                                FirstApper="SearchPageViewCellWithId_OnFirstApper"
                                                FirstDisapp="SearchPageViewCellWithId_OnFirstDisapp" 
                                                ItemId="{ Binding .,
                                                    Converter = { StaticResource ItemToIndexConverter }, 
                                                    ConverterParameter = { x:Reference AlertsListView } }">
                                                <templates:AlertItemTemplate/>
                                            </commonControls:SearchPageViewCellWithId>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>

                                <StackLayout.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger 
                                        TargetType="StackLayout"
                                        Binding="{Binding AlertsPage.Returned, Converter={ StaticResource ValueEqualToZeroConverter } }"
                                        Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger
                                       TargetType="StackLayout"
                                        Binding="{Binding IsBusy}"
                                        Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </StackLayout.Triggers>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <templates:NoChildrenFound
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                IsVisible="{ Binding ShouldShowNoChildrenFound}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Padding="20" />

                            <common:ActivityLoading
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Icon="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Bell }"
                                IsLoading="{ Binding IsBusy }"
                                LoadingText="{i18n:Translate Common.Loading}"/>

                             <!-- No Alerts Found -->
                            <common:NoDataFound 
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                IsVisible="{ Binding ShouldShowNoAlertsFound }"
                                MainText="{i18n:Translate Home.Alerts.Not.Found.MainText }"
                                DetailText="{i18n:Translate Home.Alerts.Not.Found.SecondText }">
                            </common:NoDataFound>
                </Grid>
                <!-- END GRID WRAPPER--> 

                <common:ErrorOcurred 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{ Binding ErrorOccurred }"
                    MainText="{i18n:Translate Home.Profile.Load.Error}"/>


           </Grid>
           <!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confusing about what's your desire we help. The code snipet doesn't match with the image. Your problem is with the ListView and the TapGestureRecognizer or about the white line between the yellow and red parts?

Comment: Hi, I want to split the screen into two parts. The first block (yellow) will occupy 250 fixed. The rest of the free space I want it to occupy the block of red. If the layout is posed with a two-row Grid, the TapGestureRecognizers and the ListView scroll that are in the red block do not work.

Comment: If I use a StackLayout instead of a Grid, everything works fine. But I can not get the red block to occupy the rest of the free space

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code that uses the TapGestureRecognizer, once it's the title of the question and the best option to your scenario. It should works. Whatever, I'm proposing an answer to your second choice.

Comment: Okay, I wanted it to be brief. I update my question. Thank you so much.

Comment: The block with the comment "<! - PROFILE HEADER ->" is the yellow block. The next StackLayout is the red block. This is the one with the ListView "AlertsListView". Where Scroll Can not Be Done

Comment: I'm analysing the code. Your components must be overlaping the layout bounds, then you can't handle the events.

Comment: Ok, but I do not understand what part. I have analyzed the layout many times and I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your XAML code to this (you need to test, I couldn't do it here):

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
    <Grid RowSpacing="0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- APP Header -->
        <common:AppHeader 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Title="{i18n:Translate Page.Home.Title}"
            BackEnable="false">
            <common:AppHeader.Options>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
                    <common:RefreshOptionMenu />
                    <common:SettingsOptionMenu />
                    <common:SignOutOptionMenu />
                </x:Array>
            </common:AppHeader.Options>

        </common:AppHeader>
        <!-- End APP Header -->

        <!--GRID WRAPPER-->
        <Grid 
             Grid.Row="1"
             Padding="0" 
             IsVisible="{ Binding ErrorOccurred , Converter = { StaticResource InverseBoolConverter }  }">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="250" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- PROFILE HEADER-->
            <Grid 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Padding="0">

                <!-- BACKGROUND IMAGE -->
                <Image 
                    Source="{ StaticResource HomeBackground }"
                    IsOpaque="false"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <StackLayout

                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Spacing="20">

                    <Grid 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        TranslationY="25">

                        <!-- AVATAR -->
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                            x:Name="profileImage"
                            CacheType="Disk"
                            CacheDuration="30"
                            WidthRequest="100"
                            HeightRequest="100"
                            FadeAnimationEnabled="true"
                            ErrorPlaceholder="{ StaticResource ProfileErrorImage }"
                            LoadingPlaceholder="{ StaticResource ProfileImagePlaceholder }"
                            Source="{ Binding SelfParent.ProfileImage , Converter={ StaticResource ParentProfileImageURLConverter } }">
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                                 <fftransformations:CircleTransformation BorderSize="5" BorderHexColor="#FFFFFF" />
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage.Transformations>
                         </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

                          <!-- BADGE -->
                          <common:Badge
                            IsVisible="{ Binding  AlertsPage.Remaining, Converter={ StaticResource ValueGreaterThanZeroConverter }}"
                            BadgeText="{ Binding  AlertsPage.Remaining, StringFormat='+ {0}'}"
                            BadgeTextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }"
                            BadgeBackgroundColor="#22c064"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            TranslationX="40">

                            <common:Badge.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToAlertsCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                            </common:Badge.GestureRecognizers>

                        </common:Badge>

                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding TakePhotoCommand }"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Parent FullName -->
                    <StackLayout
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Padding="20">

                        <Label 
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding SelfParent.FullName}"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble
                                PortraitPhone=22,
                                LandscapePhone=22,
                                PortraitTablet=24,
                                LandscapeTablet=24 }"  />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <!-- TOOLBAR -->
                <Grid
                    x:Name="MenuGrid"
                    VerticalOptions="End"
                    Style="{ StaticResource ToolbarStyle }"
                    BackgroundColor="{ DynamicResource TranslucidWhite }">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <!-- Children Action -->
                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Spacing="0">

                        <Label
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Users }"
                            FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">

                            <Label.FontSize>
                                <OnIdiom 
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                    Phone="15" 
                                    Tablet="20" />
                            </Label.FontSize>
                        </Label>

                        <Label
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding SelfParent.Children, StringFormat={i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Children} }"
                            TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">
                            <Label.FontSize>
                                <OnIdiom 
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                    Phone="15" 
                                    Tablet="20" />
                            </Label.FontSize> 
                        </Label>

                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToChildrenCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                     </StackLayout>

                       <!-- IsEnabled="{ Binding SelfParent.Children, Converter={ StaticResource ValueGreaterThanZeroConverter }}" -->
                      <!-- Results Action -->
                      <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Spacing="0">

                            <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.AreaChart }"
                                FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom 
                                        x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                        Phone="15" 
                                        Tablet="20" />
                                 </Label.FontSize> 
                             </Label>

                              <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Results}"
                                TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">

                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom 
                                        x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                        Phone="15"
                                        Tablet="20" />
                                 </Label.FontSize> 
                            </Label>

                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToResultsCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- Profile Action -->
                    <StackLayout
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Spacing="0">

                            <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.User }"
                                FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
                                TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom 
                                        x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                        Phone="15" 
                                        Tablet="20" />
                                </Label.FontSize> 
                            </Label>

                            <Label
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{i18n:Translate Home.Toolbar.Profile}"
                                TextColor="{ DynamicResource OverImageTextColor }">
                                <Label.FontSize>
                                    <OnIdiom 
                                        x:TypeArguments="x:Double" 
                                        Phone="15" 
                                        Tablet="20" />
                                </Label.FontSize> 
                            </Label>

                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToProfileCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                       </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <!-- END PROFILE HEADER-->

           <StackLayout 
                    x:Name="Body"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Padding="0">

                    <StackLayout
                        Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <StackLayout  
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">

                            <Label
                                FontSize="18"
                                Style="{ StaticResource CommonHeaderStyle }"
                                Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Inbox }"
                                FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }" />

                            <Label
                                Style="{ StaticResource CommonHeaderStyle }"
                                Text="{ Binding ListAlertTitle }"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalOptions="End">

                            <Label
                                FontSize="14"
                                HeightRequest="46"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{ i18n:Translate Home.Show.Alerts }"/>

                            <Label
                                Text="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.ArrowRight }"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }" />

                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{ Binding GoToAlertsCommand }" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" /> 
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <!-- Last Alerts LIST -->
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="AlertsListView"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AlertsPage.Alerts}"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        RowHeight="90">

                        <ListView.Behaviors>
                            <utils:EventToCommandBehavior 
                                EventName="ItemTapped"
                                Command="{Binding ShowAlertDetailCommand}"
                                EventArgsConverter="{ StaticResource ItemTappedEventArgsConverter }" />
                        </ListView.Behaviors>

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <commonControls:SearchPageViewCellWithId 
                                    FirstApper="SearchPageViewCellWithId_OnFirstApper"
                                    FirstDisapp="SearchPageViewCellWithId_OnFirstDisapp" 
                                    ItemId="{ Binding .,
                                        Converter = { StaticResource ItemToIndexConverter }, 
                                        ConverterParameter = { x:Reference AlertsListView } }">
                                    <templates:AlertItemTemplate/>
                                </commonControls:SearchPageViewCellWithId>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <StackLayout.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger 
                            TargetType="StackLayout"
                            Binding="{Binding AlertsPage.Returned, Converter={ StaticResource ValueEqualToZeroConverter } }"
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger
                           TargetType="StackLayout"
                            Binding="{Binding IsBusy}"
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </StackLayout.Triggers>
                </StackLayout>

                <templates:NoChildrenFound
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{ Binding ShouldShowNoChildrenFound}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Padding="20" />

                <common:ActivityLoading
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Icon="{ x:Static helper:FontAwesomeFont.Bell }"
                    IsLoading="{ Binding IsBusy }"
                    LoadingText="{i18n:Translate Common.Loading}"/>

                 <!-- No Alerts Found -->
                <common:NoDataFound 
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{ Binding ShouldShowNoAlertsFound }"
                    MainText="{i18n:Translate Home.Alerts.Not.Found.MainText }"
                    DetailText="{i18n:Translate Home.Alerts.Not.Found.SecondText }">
                </common:NoDataFound>
            </Grid>
            <!-- END GRID WRAPPER--> 

            <common:ErrorOcurred 
                Grid.Row="1"
                IsVisible="{ Binding ErrorOccurred }"
                MainText="{i18n:Translate Home.Profile.Load.Error}"/>


       </Grid>
       <!-- END MAIN CONTAINER -->
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But if you don't mind, I 'ld like give you an advice: choose the correct layouts for your need. Besides the performance, you'll get rid of a lotta unnecessary code. See [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/#Choose_the_Correct_Layout) for more information.

I hope it helps you.